# Mysterious space at beginning when string returned from a function

Tags: function, coldfusion

Why is there a space at the beginning of the string returned from a function?
The solutions seems easy but I am unable to find the reason.

**Code**

```
<cffunction name="getString" returntype="string">
    <cfreturn "hello">
</cffunction>
<cfoutput>  
[#getString()#] = getString()
</cfoutput>
```

**Output**

```
[ hello] = getString()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default CFML functions will produce output, including whitespace. This can cause unwanted white space.  Add output="false" to your function.

```
<cffunction name="encodeMyPath" returntype="string" output="false">
```

Comment: Output is _NOT_ defaulted to true. There are _three_ output states - the default/unset will output content, but setting output=true will act as if wrapped in `<cfoutput>` (and setting output=false will act as if wrapped in `<cfsilent>`).

Comment: I have updated my answer, thanks for the correction. I forget that detail because I learned it wrong initially.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and it is quite interesting to know all 3 parts.